# Rust target specific build dependencies in cross compilation

Tags: rust, cross-compiling

I have a library that supports both Windows and Linux. However, on Windows, it requires some C++ code, so I use the `cc` crate for that purpose.

```
[target.'cfg(windows)'.build-dependencies]
cc = "1.0"
```

In my build.rs, I used `#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]` for conditional compilation before.

```
fn main() {
    #[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
    {
        use cc::Build;
        println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=Kernel32");
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, I want to support **cross-compilation**, so I modified my `build.rs` to read `CARGO_CFG_TARGET_OS` to determine the target platform, like

```
    let target_os = env::var("CARGO_CFG_TARGET_OS");
    if target_os.is_ok() && target_os.unwrap() == "windows" {
        // ...
    }
```

But because I changed the conditional logic to an if statement, it resulted in the `cc` crate being required even when compiling the Linux target. How can I modify it to only install `cc` when host is Windows or cross target is Windows?